# Access global variable from an anonymous function assemblyscript

Tags: lambda, closures, assemblyscript

I'm trying to process assemblyscript arrays using the functional syntax.

However, when I try to access variable outside the scope of the functions I get an error:

Example

```
ts.values.filter(t => t.someField == ts.someField)
```

I get an error `Cannot find name 'ts'` for the `ts.someField` access within the function.

How can I add ts to the closure of my anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently AssemblyScript not support closures (only anonymous functions). See [related issue](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/798). We still have not found consensus on how to best implement this.

As workaround you could move "ts" object to global scope or use loop instead functional approach.